# Blender is crashing sometimes and not others depending on what file is loaded

Tags: customization

I am having trouble figuring out why I can't open Blender but remember having a similar issue but can't remember hos I fixed it. I made a large scene on my onboard graphics card when I was stuck with an analog monitor and had no choice, very slow and painful, but now have new monitor and tried to open my project but blender crashed straight away. I then attempted to load a smaller file and it opened without problem. I thought this must be because I have to change the graphics unit to my card in user preferences, but user preferences crashes blender. Any ideas considering that getting into settings is not doable? Should I start the computer with the onboard card and then change the settings before starting windows with the GFX? Would that even work? It's a pretty important file as it is meant to be the splash for my business page.

Debug results
C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe" --debug-memory --debug-gpumem --debug-all > results.txt.
SRNA Subclassed: 'Context'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'

SRNA Subclassed: 'PropertyGroup'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Bone'

SRNA Subclassed: 'EditBone'

SRNA Subclassed: 'PoseBone'

SRNA Subclassed: 'UIList'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Mesh'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Object'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Texture'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Header'

SRNA Subclassed: 'KeyingSetInfo'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Node'

SRNA Subclassed: 'NodeInternal'

SRNA Subclassed: 'ShaderNode'

SRNA Subclassed: 'CompositorNode'

SRNA Subclassed: 'TextureNode'

SRNA Subclassed: 'WindowManager'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'

SRNA Subclassed: 'RenderEngine'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'

SRNA Subclassed: 'PropertyGroup'

SRNA Subclassed: 'AddonPreferences'

I1219 09:13:16.978374  5296 blender_python.cpp:186] Debug flags initialized to:

CPU flags:

AVX2   : True

AVX    : True

SSE4.1 : True

SSE3   : True

SSE2   : True

QBVH   : True

Split  : False

CUDA flags:
 Adaptive Compile: False

OpenCL flags:
  Device type    : ALL
  Kernel type    : DEFAULT
  Debug          : False
  Single program : True
  Memory limit   : zu

SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'

SRNA Subclassed: 'NodeTree'

SRNA Subclassed: 'NodeSocket'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'AddonPreferences'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'

SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'

I1219 09:13:18.370613  5296 device_opencl.cpp:59] CLEW initialization succeeded.

Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Comment: You could try "File -> Defaults -> Load Factory Settings". This will effectively reset all of your Blender settings, opening it as if you were opening it for the first time.

Comment: That seems to crash it also.

Comment: What Blender version are you using and what is your CPU and GPU? Have you tried updating your graphics driver?

Comment: Driver to the latest version and 2.79b however it seems to affect all the 2.79 versions even the last release. GTX 560 ti, fermi architecture, and a celeron dual core. CPU could be a limiting factor but I haven't had problems with it before. The problem I am facing is that I cannot seem to completely remove every trace of an old blender version. It is something in user setting.blend in appdata, or the usersettings them self found in the blender folder. I tried to remove them but subsequent reinstalls didn't replace them. i have tried the zip version, which load perfectly but can't find the GPU

Comment: Opening up a virtual machine with a fresh windows 10 on it and my second GTX 560 ti given full allowance for the VM, it worked perfectly. There is something wrong with my installation and uninstalling it and reinstalling it won't change the settings. Something is saved after uninstall that makes the problem persist.